# WebBrowser.Navigate open default browser

Tags: vb.net, process, http-post, webbrowser-control

WebBrowser.Navigate always opens IE. Is there a way WebBrowser to open the default browser?

I use WebBrowser because I need to send Post data, so using Process.Start does not work for me because I am unable to send post data.

Thanks

Comment: `WebBrowser.Navigate()` probably opens IE because the `WebBrowser` component is IE based. Could you show us an example of how you do it?

Comment: This guy's solution was to create a .html page on the fly. See the edit in his question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091031/c-sharp-open-web-page-in-default-browser-with-post-data